# PHP Regex Match ! or * anywhere in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm a beginner in using Regex and have been struggling to create a pattern that can search for a single match of either ! or * anywhere in my string. The full requirements I am looking for are:

- Start with a letter
- Contain at least 1 number
- Between 8-16 characters
- Contain at least one ! or *

What I have so far is:

```
^[A-Za-z](!*)[A-Za-z0-9]{6,14}$
```

Clearly I'm using parenthesis incorrectly, but I'm still playing around with it and trying different things. What I am specifically struggling with is searching for a single instance of ! or * in *any location*.

If anyone can kindly provide a hint, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^[A-Za-z](?=.*[!*])(?=.*\d).{7,15}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vIKdJ5/1)

Explanation:

- `^`: Start
- `[A-Za-z]`: Match a letter
- `(?=.*[!*])`: Lookahead to assert that we have at least one `*` or `!`
- `(?=.*\d)`: Lookahead to assert that we have at least one digit
- `.{7,15}$`: Match 7 to 15 characters (we matched a letter at start)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z](?=.*\d)(?=.*[!*])[A-Za-z\d!*]{7,15}$
```

Here (?=.*) means that the order of things you want to exist doesn't matter but they have to be in the string at least one time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response and explanation! (?=.*) is definitely something I didn't understand prior to your comment